# Displaying a custom field containing a list creates unwanted markup

Tags: custom-field

I display my custom field like this :

```
<p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $my_field, true); ?></p>
```

As long as the field contains plain text, the markup is normal :

```
<p>something</p>
```

But if I put some HTML list in it, the content jumps out of the P tags and some additional P tags are even added :

```
<p></p>
<ul>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

Why is that and how to fix the problem ?

Comment: Is this just the output from your browser’s debugger or a real source code view?

Comment: I see that in Firebug. In the browser I see that the custom field content jumped out of the P tags because there's a style (thick left border) on this tag and the content is below it.

Answer (score 1):

Let `wpautop()` do the work:

```
echo wpautop( get_post_meta($post->ID, $my_field, true) );
```

`wpautop()` will detect leading block elements and use `<p>` only when the value starts with a string.

Comment: Same result : http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/wordpress_test/?p=18
As long as I display the custom field between P tags, using wpautop or not, it will jump out of the P tags if it contains UL and LI elements.

Comment: @drake035 Note that my solution does **not** include manual `p` tags, let `wpautop()` add those.

Comment: Thanks toscho. It works when I remove manual p tags. However it works without using wpautop() anyway as long as there's no manual p tags. Using div tags instead of p tags I don't have any problem. Still, this doesn't explain this weird behaviour : why does the content jump out of the p tags like that? I see no logical reason for this.

Comment: That happens because a `p` element cannot contain block elements. The browser has to close it to open the next block element.

Comment: Hm I didn't know that, thanks a lot toscho.